# Ruby on Rails Index Action, Display Records

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, activerecord

Sorry for the ignorant question, I'm new to Ruby on Rails.

I have 3 models - Employer, Employee and Announcement

The Announcement model belongs_to the Employer
The Employer has_many Announcements
The Employee belongs_to the Employer

Currently I'm able to display the Announcements that belong_to an Employer using

`@announcements = Announcement.where(:employer_id => current_employer.id)`

I'm having trouble display the Announcements that belong to an Employer to the Employee.

What query would I use to do this

Comment: What is relation between employee and announcement ? also between employee and employer.

Comment: has_many through :employer.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to frequently use this `Employee` and `Announcement` relationship then make a new relation of `has_many through` like:

```
Class Employee
  has_one :employer
  has_many :announcements, through: :employer
end
```

Then you can directly have announcements belonging to the employee by simply doing:

```
@employee.announcements
```

And for deep understanding you can refer to [2.4 The has_many :through Association](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html)

Answer (score 0):

Given the information that you have provided I think you want to Display the announcements for a specific employees, employer. Eg:

```
Employee -> Employer -> Announcement
```

In this case you could do something like:

```
@employeer = Employee.employeer #assuming this is a one-to-one relationship
@announcements = Announcement.where(:employer_id => @employeer.id)
```

Comment: Thanks for the response. I'm wanting to display the Announcements to an Employee, and the announcements belong an Employer. The Employee belongs_to and Employer. And the Employer has_many Employees

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to display all of the Employer's announcements using

```
current_employer.announcements
```

Assuming the Employer has_many Employees, given a single @employee

```
@employee.employer.announcements
```

Answer (score 0):

As per your your question requirement. You are not having proper association. You should have following association.

employer has_many announcements

```
Class Employer
  has_many :announcements
  has_many :employees, through :announcements
end

Class Employee
  belongs_to :announcement
end

Class Announcement
  belongs_to :employer, through :announcements
  belongs_to :announcement
end
```

Now find it like this :

```
@announcements = current_employer.announcements
```

And employees like this :

```
@announcements.each do |announcement|
  @employees = announcement.employees
end
```

Answer (score 0):

**Associations**

Firstly, you should not be calling a `.where` query on your associative data:

```
@announcements = Announcement.where(:employer_id => current_employer.id)
```

Since you're new to RoR, I'd recommend having a quick read of the [ActiveRecord Association](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html) documentation to give you a much richer understanding of how the associations work.

Specifically, you want to make sure that every time you have *associated* data, you should be able to call it from your "parent" object. ActiveRecord will take your associations & automatically load the required data (with the help of `foreign_keys`):

```
@announcements = current_employer.accouncements
```

--

**Fix**

In order to get it working, you'll want to do this:

```
#app/models/employer.rb
class Employer < ActiveRecord::Base
   has_many :employees
   has_many :announcements
end

#app/models/employee.rb
class Employee < ActiveRecord::Base
   belongs_to :employer
   delegate :announcements, to: :employer
end

#app/models/announcement.rb
class Announcement < ActiveRecord::Base
   belongs_to :employer
end
```

This will give you the ability to call the following:

```
@employee = current_employer.employees.find 1
@announcements = @employee.announcements
```